# How can I measure network traffic?

Tags: iphone, ipad, networking, ios4

For example as Download Meter app does. Can I track packages dispatched? Does iOS a traffic tracking system that I can poll somewhere?

Comment: Did you get any luck to access network traffic in iphone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XCode -> Run with Performance Tool -> Select Activity Monitor -> Open Library and add Network Activity Tool. Remember it will capture ALL network activities from your phone, not just your app's traffic. You will need to determine "white noise" traffic subtract from overall sampling. Good luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`vnstat` under Linux.

There's a nice graphical representation for it, made with rrdtool.

**Edit**

Sorry, didn't see it's for iPad. please clarify your machine and OS next time...